# "Authorize up to $3000 payment" vs. "authorize up to $3000 in payment"

Tags: prepositions, writing-style

Does there need to be a preposition in this sentence? It just feels awkward…

> The Commission may authorize up to $3,000.00 payment for expenses of an eligible person or an eligible dependent family member.

When I read it, it feels like there should be an "in" after "$3,000.00." Or alternatively, the article "a" should be before "$3,000.00."

This is something that I've been asked to edit and this just feels incomplete.

How would you rewrite this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/payment), *payment* is can be a count noun or a mass noun:

> **payment**
>
> noun
>
> **1** [mass noun] the action or process of paying someone or something or of being paid:
>
> *ask for a discount for payment by cash*
>
> [count noun]:
>
> *three interest-free monthly payments*
>
> **2** an amount paid or payable:
>
> *a compensation payment of £2500*
>
> [mass noun] something given as a reward or in recompense for something done:
>
> *a suit with a velvet collar that I got as payment for being in the show*

That suggests to me that *payment* doesn't need to be quantified, and that otherwise the sentence doesn't need changing.

If I had to, though, I would probably go with the previous answer of

> The Commission may authorize payment of up to $3,000.00 for expenses

The phrase "*a [single] payment of...*" implies that there will only be a single payment. Unless you know this to be the case and want to specify it, I would not use that. *Payment* on its own should be fine.

Comment: So if the payment described **is** indeed a one time event, then it would need precise quantification? But it's different if it implies an ongoing series of actions?

Comment: @toots I edited my answer to make it a bit clearer (hopefully). If it is a single transaction then "a payment" would be correct. If it could be multiple transactions then "a payment" would be incorrect (or confusing).

Answer (score 3):

“Up to $3,000.00 payment for …” does sound awkward to me, too.

I would either, as you suggest, add a preposition:

> The Commission may authorize up to $3,000.00 ***in*** payment for expenses …

– or I would recast the sentence a bit:

> The Commission may authorize payment of up to $3,000.00 for expenses …

You can say “a $3,000.00 payment for expenses …”, but when you add ‘up to’, the indefinite article becomes impossible, and the resulting phrase is clunky. Adding the preposition changes the $3,000.00 from being an attributive noun modifying ‘payment’ to being the head of the noun phrase, modified by the prepositional phrase ‘in payment [for…]’.

Comment: Can anyone put a finger on precisely why the sentence as originally written feels awkward?

Comment: Formal syntax rules aren’t really my forte, but it would seem to me that a countable (singular) noun that is modified generally must be specified for definiteness to sound idiomatic in a sentence (except in telegraphic style). Thus “$3,000.00 payment” is awkward, while “***a*** $3,000.00 payment” is fine.